# Can zsh read reserved terminal keyword?

Tags: zsh

Normally, if I type 'clear' in the shell(zsh), then the contents shown are cleared.

And, here is what I want to do.

If I type 'clear', the shell would be cleared, and also logging some message which I intend to make.

So I fixed `.zshrc` like below,

```
clear()
{
    read REPLY

    if[[[ $REPLY =~ "clear"]]
    then
        echo "some message"
    fi
}
```

So I expected that if I type 'clear', contents on the shell would be cleared and "some message" would also be prompted.

But only the message "some message" comes out.

How can I read that reserved "clear" command, not the string itself?

Comment: Please fix the syntax error in your posting (i.e. the `if` statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not clear the screen. For doing this, you have to issue a `clear` command. But since your function is also called `clear`, simply typing `clear` inside the function would lead to infinite recursion. As a solution, use

```
command clear
```

instead. The prefix `command` bypasses the function definition.

Comment: thanks, so you mean

clear()
{
    read REPLY

    if[[ $REPLY =~  command clear]]
    then
        echo "some message"
    fi
}

Comment: if I use command clear instead of clear(){}, actual clear does not happen

Comment: NOT instead of `clear(){}`. This makes no sense! Do a `command clear` just before the `echo`.